# Is it possible to rewrite a page url Without setting the permalinks to Post Name?

Tags: pages, url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

Is it possible to rewrite the page url if your page link is for example `localhost/wordpress/?p=123` ? Instead of `post_name.php?...`. (So the first option of permalinks and not `post_name`.

Comment: I don't understand this question, and besides there are countless posts here and elsewhere about permalinks and rewrite rules. What have you done to try to solve this yourself?

Comment: if you don't have pretty permalinks enabled, requests for anything outside WordPress index.php is handled by your server and completely bypasses WordPress.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I've tried rewriting it but the question should be alright? I've searched around and about it, all i've came across was `post_name` being enabled.

@Milo Submit this as answer as this answered my question. Also thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this was not working is due to `Localhost` you apparently can't do this without having a online wordpress site. Locally this is not possible.